# Exchange the tags of all elements of a class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, queryselector

```js
var f = document.querySelector('.example');
var g = document.createElement('h2');
for (let i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    g.innerHTML = f[i].innerHTML;
    f[i].parentNode.replaceChild(g, f[i]);
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="example">Hi</li>
<li class="example">Hi</li>
<li class="example">Hi</li>
<li class="example">Hi</li>
<li class="example">Hi</li>
<li class="example">Hi</li>
<li class="example">Hi</li>
</ul>
```

here is what I would like to do:

I want to make accessibility adjustments to a WordPress theme with JavaScript afterwards.

In the following case i want to overwrite **all** element-tags of the class ".example" with the tag `<h2>` (currently they are `<div>`)

With the code example here I only reach the first element (I know that), but i want to "overwrite" **all** of them with the new tag:

```
var f = document.querySelector('.example');
var g = document.createElement('h2');
g.innerHTML = f.innerHTML;
f.parentNode.replaceChild(g, f);
```

How do i do that, i have already tried something like:

```
var f = document.querySelector('.example');
var g = document.createElement('h2');
for (let i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    g.innerHTML = f[i].innerHTML;
    f[i].parentNode.replaceChild(g, f);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I think that should be simple, but I am a newbie.

Thank you :)

Comment: You forgot the index in the argument to `replaceChild`: `replaceChild(g, f[i])`

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you. But that was not the issue. Still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: For sure, thank you for your help, is that okay?: https://jsfiddle.net/dgcyerqz/1/

Comment: Stack Snippet is very similar to jsfiddle, so we prefer that you post here instead of at a remote site. I even gave you a link to the instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new `<h2>` element each time through the loop, not reuse the same element `g`. And you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all the `.example` elements so you can loop over them.

```js
var f = document.querySelectorAll('.example');
for (let i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
  var g = document.createElement('h2');
  g.innerHTML = f[i].innerHTML;
  f[i].parentNode.replaceChild(g, f[i]);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="example">Hi</li>
  <li class="example">Hi</li>
  <li class="example">Hi</li>
  <li class="example">Hi</li>
  <li class="example">Hi</li>
  <li class="example">Hi</li>
  <li class="example">Hi</li>
</ul>
```